# Extracting non-spatial data from imported KML file using R?

Tags: r, kml, sp, rgdal

I have a KML file which was created using Google's My Maps.

The original file can be downloaded here: 
[Google My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1gO383FN6XS89neIm_MIU6nTPKvoY9AQE&ll=31.926485203171666%2C123.38307069224663&z=4)

Using R, I can import this using the "readOGR" function of the rgdal library
This brings the KML file in as a SpatialPointsDataFrame (SPDF) - which i am calling asf52

[image: ![RStudio Data Pane]

In this SPDF, the spatial data is contained under @coords and is readily extracted into a dataframe using code like

```
df  <- data.frame(asf52@coords[,1:2])
```

However, I am struggling to come up with a way to neatly extract the the non-spatial data - contained under @data$Description - and turn it into a dataframe with a column for each variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `data.frame()` around the extract - the `@data` slot already is a data.frame. Just do

```
  df <- asf52@data
```

to pull out a copy. That said, you may be better served by using the newer `sf` library for this task:

```
library(sf)
ob_kml <- file.path(getwd(), 'Outbreaks 56 (OIE).kml')
```

There is more than one layer in your KML - list them with e.g.

```
st_layers(ob_kml)
```

Use `read_sf()` with the `layers` argument to choose your point data specifically and read it in. `read_sf()` defaults to stringsAsFactors = FALSE which may be preferable.

```
asf_c <- read_sf(ob_kml, layer = 'ASF in China.xlsx')
```

To get a plain dataframe, just drop the geometry as follows:

```
asf_c_df <- st_set_geometry(asf_c, NULL)
```

**EDIT:** I see your secondary issue now; it looks like neither `sf` nor `sp` look at the `<ExtendedData>` tags that hold the attribute data you want (open the KML in Notepad++ if you want to see what I mean). QGIS does detect and import them as separate attribute columns, so @Jella's advice is sound. I'm not sure if the issue here lies with `sf`/`sp` or GDAL, but it may be worth raising an issue of the `sf` github page.

In the meantime, your instinct to go with `tidyr` functions is sound, its just a little tricky to get a clean separation. The following looks pretty good:

```
asf_c_df <- st_set_geometry(asf_c, NULL) %>%
  # remove duplicate <br> tags
  dplyr::mutate(Description = gsub('<br><br>', '<br>', Description)) %>%
  # split on <br>
  tidyr::separate(., col = Description, 
                  into = c('Date', 'Province', 'City', 'County', 'Location', 
                           'Total_herd_size', 'Affected_animals', 'Deaths',
                           'Culled', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Source'), 
                  sep = '<br>') %>%
  # ditch the key: part of key: value
  dplyr::mutate_all(., funs(gsub('^.*: ', '', .))) %>%
  # data type fixes 
  dplyr::mutate_at(vars(7:10), as.integer) %>%
  dplyr::mutate_at(vars(11,12), as.numeric) %>%
  # bonus points: proper dates. First, fix September, then cast to Date datatype
  dplyr::mutate(Date = gsub('Sept', 'Sep', Date),
                Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = '%b %d, %Y')) %>%
  # double bonus! proper NA for missing data
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.character, funs(ifelse(. == '', NA, .)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed suggestions, all of which I have followed. However, the problem remains in that all the description data is placed into one column. This seems to be a limitation of how both read_sf() and readOGR() are handling the KML file, and thus I will need to wait until this is changed to accommodate this format.  In the meantime, I will explore post-import parsing of the column using functions like separate() in the tidyr package.

Comment: The issue lies in the KML file as all the informatio is stored in the description to show a nice pop-up in a GIS viewer. KML files are not able to store a proper attribute table.

Comment: Well spotted, @Jelle, the issue is both sp and sf fail to parse the KML structure completely.

Comment: @obrl_soil, When I open the KML file in Google Earth, you get the same issue. So I think it's rather the limitation of (this particular) kml file than an issue with the sp or sf package.

Comment: @Jelle I'm not so sure - my first instinct was to blame the GDAL kml driver, but QGIS should be using that too, and its doing the right thing...

Comment: @obrl_soil I see what you mean now. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed research, helpful comments and tidyr code - which worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Like what you did with @coords, use `asf52@data` to extract the non-spatial data through a dataframe. You can call the description column through `asf52@data$description`

Comment: Yes this is what I tried, i.e.: `df_2 <- data.frame(asf52@data$Description)`. The code runs, but the result is all the data is put into a single column.

Comment: You mean both ‘name’ and ‘description’?

Comment: Yes - both the name and the data are concatenated into a single column. This is the result of running `str(df_2)`: 'data.frame': 52 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ asf52.data.Description: Factor w/ 52 levels "Date: Aug 1, 2018<br>Province: Liaoning<br>City: Shenyang<br>County: Shenbei New District<br>Location: Shenbei "| __truncated__,..: 1 12 14 13 15 2 3 5 4 6 ...

Comment: The data frame returns 1 variable, being $description. What do you see if you observe the data.frame through View(asf52)?

Comment: All the description data is in one column. If I run 'head(asf52$Description, n=2)'  - to show the first two rows - I get: [1] "Date: Aug 1, 2018<br>Province: Liaoning<br>City: Shenyang<br>County: Shenbei New District<br>Location: Shenbei Street<br>Total herd size: 19420<br>Affected animals: 47<br>Deaths: 47<br>Culled: 19373<br>Latitude: 42.0225<br><br>Longitude: 123.2932<br>Source: OIE"
[2] "Date: Aug 7, 2018<br>Province: Liaoning<br>City: Shenyang<br>County: Shenbei New District<br>Location: Cailuo Yi Village<br>Total herd size: 160<br>Affected .......

Comment: I think I might understand your problem now. You mean that Date, Province, City etc. Are not separated into separated columns? If so, does the kml file have separate fields for all the data or do they all fall under Description? Because I see <br>, it looks like all the info is stored in the Description field in the kml file.

Comment: So I took a look at your KML file. The isse lies in the KML file. All the information is stored as a description with <br> so that it can be shown as a pop up in a GIS viewer. KML files are not able to make attribute table as what .shp files can. If you want to avoid post-import parsing, you might want to import a KML file in a GIs software first (like QGIS) to make a proper attribute table.